# Can we craft multiple traits on a single item?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

There are 9 different traits that can be researched for each armor or weapon piece. When crafting an item, what is the maximum traits that can be added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, only 1 trait can be added to an item piece while crafting.

Note that there are *set items* in the game which have trait *research* requirements, as in knowing 2 or more traits researched for that item before crafting a set version. However, those traits aren't automatically added to the crafted piece nor do the exact traits matter at all. You can still add a seperate trait to a set item, but again it will be limited to a *single* trait only.

Comment: Thank you for making this. I was wondering the same thing, but never made it far enough into the game to find out, firsthand.